# Python how to return more than one value

Tags: python-3.x

How do I return more than one possible value? (Two sum problem: Determine if any two number inside an array sum to a number A)

I already figure out how to kind of solve the problem.

```
def twoSum(arr, A):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] + arr[j] == A:
                return(arr[i], arr[j])
                
print(twoSum([1,2,3,4],5))
```

However, I only manage to return the first possible value. Although (2, 3) is also correct.

```
my output: (1, 4)
```

Is there a way to return multiple values such as

```
intended output: [(1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you return a single value in a form of a `tuple`, only thing you need to do is to create a collection and add possible value pairs to that one. You can use a `list` for that like the below:

```py
def twoSum(arr, A):
    sum_values = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] + arr[j] == A:
                sum_values.append((arr[i], arr[j]))
    return sum_values


print(twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4], 5))
```

So in this example you have the `sum_values` variable to collect all possible combinations of sums, and you return value will be the `list` of these sum pairs.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it before but got an error. Then I compared to your answer. Seems like I forgot the additional bracket when appending. I wrote `answer.append(arr[i], arr[j])` instead of `answer.append((arr[i], arr[j]))`. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

check numpy library for more dimensional arrays, you can easily solve it